# Platform update - Move from RC1 to RC2 - not application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

my question is not about migrating projects but about the platform. I I have on a win10 box VS 2k15, MS ASP.Net 5 RC1 Update 1 with .Net Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6 and 4.6.1 (Multi-Targeting Pack, Targeting Pack)
I read at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows 
*Remove all previous versions of .NET Core from your system by using Add/Remove programs*
So should I remove all of the above aa you can notice in the snapshot hereunder

[snapshot of my Programs and Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unlyd.jpg)